# I'm having trouble returning a boolean from my nodejs server to my angular service

Tags: node.js, angular

I'm trying to use a log in with angular and want to return a boolean that says that I am logged in, but its not returning it even though I put it as a service.

Here is the server code

```
var loggedin = Boolean;
app.post('/auth', function(request,response){
var username = request.body.username;
var password = request.body.password;
console.log(username);
console.log(password);
if(username && password){
connection.query('SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username = ? AND password = ?', [username,password], function(error,results,fields){
    if (results.length > 0){
        request.session.loggedin = true;
        request.session.username = username;
        // response.redirect('/home');
        console.log("Credentials are correct!")
        //res.send(result);
        loggedin = true;
        response.send(loggedin)
    } else{
        response.send('Incorrect login details!');
        console.log("Wrong credentials!")
        loggedin = false;
    }
    response.end();

});
} else {
    response.send('Please enter your username and or password');
    response.end();
}});
```

Angular component

```
export class LoginbarComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private modalService: NgbModal,private service:PostService{}

  Logres: Boolean = false;


  ngOnInit() {

  }

  private obj : any  = {"Email": "", "pass" : ""};
test(){

this.service.PostLogin(this.obj.Email,this.obj.pass);
console.log(this.obj.Email,this.obj.pass);

this.service.GetResponse().subscribe(logres =>{
  this.Logres=logres;
})}
```

Angular service

```
GetResponse(){
return this.http.get<Boolean>('http://localhost:3000/auth')}
```

full service code

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { DatabaseService } from './database.service';
    import { ForumPost } from './post';

    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class PostService {
      topics: string[] = [];
      threads: string[] = [];
      posts: PostService[] = [];


      GetTopic() {
        return this.http.get<String>("http://localhost:3000/gettopics")
      }

      Getthread(thread) {
        return this.http.get<String> 
       (`http://localhost:3000/getthread/${thread}`)
      }

      Getpost(post) {
        return this.http.get<ForumPost(`http://localhost:3000/getthread/${post}`)

      }

      GetResponse(){
        return this.http.get<Boolean>('http://localhost:3000/auth')

      }

      PostLogin(username,password){
        console.log("Username:" +username);
        console.log("Password:" +password);
         this.http.post("http://localhost:3000/auth",

         {"username":username,"password":password}).subscribe((data)=>{
        console.log(data)
      });
      }



  constructor( private http: HttpClient,
    private databaseService: DatabaseService) { 
  }
}
```

I added the rest of the code to give some background info without having to reply individually.

Comment: are you sure that `localhost:3000/auth` return a true/false?

Comment: @kris_IV When i try to console log it on the server, I get true or false depending on my input on angular. Heres a screenshot http://prntscr.com/nrhjdw

Comment: So I think that your problem description is a little bit confused - It's not a problem with `node.js` but with your notification system. Can you show more code with your component? Where you initialise `Logers` variable? How you want to display this data in your `HTML template`? Why are you using big letter for `Logers` variable? It's not a class - it's really confusing.
Please put hire your component and service.

Comment: I added the missing code, the HTML code has {{Logres}} just to see if it works

Comment: Look hire: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-typefinthechat
My service only emulate your code. It's similar like yours? If you click `Login` button you get a True after 1 second. If you see any differences feel free to edit stackblitz and give me a feedback

Comment: The problem here is that it'll always become true after submitting, I need to send a value of a bool from my node server to my angular service/component which i still haven't found

Comment: I know - its a mock, but you told before that if you use console.log inside GetResponse subscription you have a proper result. Is it?

Comment: I managed to work around the boolean by sending a string instead, but now I've come to see another bug, the first time (after start up) I send my string from the server but the console.log("heres the value", loginres) says "heres the value function string() { [ native code ] }, but after a 2nd submit click on angular, it sends the real value, that being '1' or '0'. still haven't found the cause

Comment: Why you don't send this as a JSON: `{login: true/false}` ? In this case you should declare only `content-type` to `application/json`